# How to select tables in scrapy using selectors whose class id have spaces in it?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to select all the tables inside a division which has xpath similar to `//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/table[@class="wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter"]`. But the selector doesn't returns any value. How can I get through those tags which have spaces in their id/class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say exactly what the problem is, since I don't have the source data that you are trying to parse. It would be helpful if you would paste the minimum section.

But anyhow, you have more than one choice to achieve this. I would suggest using a CSS selector in combination with XPath selector, like so:

```
response.xpath("//*[@id='mw-content-text']").css("table.wikitable.sortable.jquery-tablesorter")
```

But if you want to use only XPath, you can utilize the *contains()*:

```
response.xpath("//*[@id='mw-content-text']/table[contains(@class,'wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter')]")
```

But this could be tricky because it requires the tables *class* to be defined exactly as that, it doesn't allow for different ordering of classes. If you want to cover those cases, I suggest you use it like this:

```
response.xpath("//*[@id='mw-content-text']/table[contains(@class,'wikitable') and contains(@class, 'sortable') and contains(@class, 'jquery-tablesorter')]")
```

You can find more information on Scrapy selectors [in the official documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html).

**EDIT:**
As noticed by Rahul, the issue here is that the class `jquery-tablesorter` is in fact added dynamically by jQuery [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) plugin, and thus this class is not visible in the scrapy Response, because no JS is executed yet. To reflect this in the solution, you should not include the `jquery-tablesorter` in your selector expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem was the relative xpath in chrome browser was different than what I was getting as a response in scrapy object. Extra word `jquery-tablesorter` is added to the xpath in the browser. I just removed these words from the xpath and it worked fine. But I still don't the reason why this happend. Any information regarding this will be appreciated. This is the website [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_and_towns_in_India_by_population)

Comment: This is because the class is not present in the static page, and is introduced dynamically via JavaScript (jQuery) at a later time. More precisely, the jQuery `tablesorter` plugin (http://tablesorter.com/docs/) that is used to sort the table data dynamically is responsible for altering those classes at runtime. What you see in the scrapy Response is the contents of a page before running any JS that could change it. I have added this info to the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. One more question, Is it related to Lazy Loading of websites ?

Comment: No. Lazy loading means that content is loaded only just before it is needed. This behavior is determined by the way the plugin works, i.e. it is related to the webpage being responsive to the user input, namely ordering of the elements in a table when a user clicks on the table header column. There is no new content loaded in this case (not necessarily anyway), so we can't talk about lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue because I was trying to scrape a wikipedia page. The class name for the table shows up as `"wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter"` because of the plugin mentioned in the other answer which adds to the class name after it is used.

In order to pick up the table you can just look for the following class instead `"wikitable sortable"`. This picks up the code for me.